# Trouble with Pan by dragging in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-3.0

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Grab-to-pan in Silverlight app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2179286/grab-to-pan-in-silverlight-app)

I have a Canvas inside a ScrollViewer; the Canvas will have several objects drawn on it.
I would like to be able to Pan -- scroll -- the Canvas using the mouse:  LButtonDown - move mouse - LButtonUp.
In the .xaml, I have a TranslateTransform for the Canvas.
Code:

```
private void MapCanvas_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
        ClickPosition = e.GetPosition(MapCanvas);
        Debug.WriteLine("LButtonDown: " + ClickPosition.ToString());
        MapCanvas.CaptureMouse();
        IsMouseCaptured = true;

        e.Handled = true;
 }
 private void MapCanvas_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
 {
     if (IsMouseCaptured)
     {
         Point point = new Point(e.GetPosition(MapCanvas));
         Debug.WriteLine("\t" + point.ToString());
         MapPanTransform.X = point.X - ClickPosition.X;
         MapPanTransform.Y = point.Y - ClickPosition.Y;
     }
 }
```

This results in some strange points appearing in MapCanvas_MouseMove:
LButtonDown 557,469
    556,469
    **368,472**
    555,469
    **367,472**
    554,469
    **365,472**
    553,469

Any ideas on what's going on?
Thanks.

Comment: It feels like the MouseMove event handler is getting events from a different control.  I've tried to make sure that only the MouseMove from the canvas object I want to handle get through, but no luck yet.

Comment: One answer is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2179286/grab-to-pan-in-silverlight-app/2187282#2187282

Answer (score 0):

Are there any controls that overlay the Canvas you're trying to move?  You might look into the isHitTestVisible property.  If I understand correctly it makes mouse events transparent on a control so that all events happen on controls "below" the control where isHitTestVisible is false.

Comment: I don't think that's the issue.  Looking at the debugging output, the bold numbers are decreasing at the same rate as the non-bold, as though the MouseMove event was being sent w/r/t to a different origin.

Comment: It appears to be related to the TranslateTransform (MapPanTransform).  If I comment out those lines, the MouseMove debugging output looks like what I expect.  Of course, the map doesn't get scrolled...