# Grab-to-pan in Silverlight app

Tags: silverlight

I have a Canvas inside a ScrollViewer.  I want to have the user to be able to grab the canvas and move it around, with the thumbs on the scrollbars updating appropriately.
My initial implementation calculates the offset on each mouse move, and updates the scrollbars:

```
 // Calculate the new drag distance
 Point newOffsetPos = e.GetPosition(MapCanvas);
 System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("   newOffsetPos : " + newOffsetPos.X + " " + newOffsetPos.Y);

 double deltaX = newOffsetPos.X - _offsetPosition.X ;
 double deltaY = newOffsetPos.Y - _offsetPosition.Y ;

 System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("   delta X / Y : " + deltaX + " " + deltaY);
 System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("   sv offsets X / Y : " + _scrollViewer.HorizontalOffset + " " + _scrollViewer.VerticalOffset);

 _scrollViewer.ScrollToHorizontalOffset(_scrollViewer.HorizontalOffset - deltaX);
 _scrollViewer.ScrollToVerticalOffset(_scrollViewer.VerticalOffset - deltaY);

 _offsetPosition = newOffsetPos;
```

While this works, it is not very smooth.
Is there a better way to do this?  If Transforms are used, will the scrollbars update automagically when the Canvas is moved?
Thanks for any tips...

Comment: Hmm.. disappointing that using the ScrollViewer is too slow, interesting problem though.

Comment: It's not slow, it has strange behavior...  I suspect it is an interaction between the ScrollViewer and the Canvas when a mouse button is down.  When I hold the left button down and move the mouse steadily right, roughly every other newOffsetPos will be less than the previous, causing the Canvas to jump back and forth.

Comment: Ahh I see, I've seen this sort of thing before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually this sort of problem is really a matter of using the right pattern to track the mouse.  I've seen this issue in variety of cases not just in Silverlight.

The best pattern is to trap the original locations of both mouse and subject, then recalculate the new offset from the fixed original values.  That way the mouse stays planted solid at a single point on the image being panned.  Here is my simple Repro:-

Start with a fresh Silverlight Application in visual studio.  Modify MainPage.Xaml thus:-

```
<UserControl x:Class="SilverlightApplication1.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
        <ScrollViewer x:Name="Scroller" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
            <Image x:Name="Map" Source="test.jpg" Width="1600" Height="1200" />
        </ScrollViewer>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Add the following code to the MainPage.xaml.cs file:-

```
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Map.MouseLeftButtonDown += new MouseButtonEventHandler(Map_MouseLeftButtonDown);
    }

    void Map_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        Point mapOrigin = new Point(Scroller.HorizontalOffset, Scroller.VerticalOffset);
        Point mouseOrigin = e.GetPosition(Application.Current.RootVisual);

        MouseEventHandler moveHandler = null;
        MouseButtonEventHandler upHandler = null;

        moveHandler = (s, args) =>
        {
            Point mouseNew = args.GetPosition(Application.Current.RootVisual);
            Scroller.ScrollToHorizontalOffset(mapOrigin.X - (mouseNew.X - mouseOrigin.X));
            Scroller.ScrollToVerticalOffset(mapOrigin.Y - (mouseNew.Y - mouseOrigin.Y));
        };


        upHandler = (s, args) =>
        {
            Scroller.MouseMove -= moveHandler;
            Scroller.MouseLeftButtonUp -= upHandler;
        };

        Scroller.MouseMove += moveHandler;
        Scroller.MouseLeftButtonUp += upHandler;
    }
}
```

Give it a reasonably large test.jpg (doesn't need to be 1600x1200 `Image` will scale it).

You'll note that when dragging the mouse remains exactly over a fixed point in the image until you hit a boundary.  Move the mouse as fast as you like it always tracks, this is because it doesn't depend on deltas being accurate and up-to-date.  The only variable is the current mouse position, the other values remain fixed as they were at mouse down.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I still get the unexpected position info in the moveHandler - moving steadily to the right, note that roughly every other X coord is smaller than the previous:
mouseNew: 1296  876
  mouseNew: 1284  876
  mouseNew: 1297  876
  mouseNew: 1298  876
  mouseNew: 1286  876
  mouseNew: 1299  876
  mouseNew: 1300  876
  mouseNew: 1301  876
  mouseNew: 1287  876
Makes for not-smooth scrolling...  My scrollviewer control is 1/2 the height and width of the canvas it contains.

Comment: @Number8: Sounds like something else is dodgy on your system, works perfectly for me.  Either the `GetPosition` calcs are off at times for some reason (you are using the app `RootVisual` right?) or perhaps you might even have a dodgy mouse or driver.  Is the mouse smooth when you move it elsewhere?

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I was using the wrong element in GetPosition().

Comment: Holy crap, this just fixed a bug that has been in our app for months!!  The jumpiness was tolerated and the bug has been in our backlog for e-ver.  Thank you.

Comment: It really works flawless for me. I've just split the events in diferents methods, and also only removed the handlers after the user unload the component, this way i only add and remove once. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You could try [this](http://autoscroller.codeplex.com) (or at least take a peek at how it's implemented).

Comment: Thanks.  Not very intuitive to use, but maybe I can get some ideas for my implementation.

Comment: Hmmm... looks like it is doing what I am trying to do, update the scrollviewer offsets:  TargetScrollViewer.ScrollToHorizontalOffset(TargetScrollViewer.HorizontalOffset + ScrollPixelsPerTick);